# Let $i : U \to X$ be an open inclusion. Is $ i_* i^{-1} $ an exact functor?

Tags: sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Let $i : U \to X$ be an open inclusion. Is $ i_* i^{-1} $ an exact functor?

I think possibly not, but I am kind of convinced yes (because the maps on stalks are either the same or made into zero).

The reason why I think it is not is because I am reading about sheaf cohomology, and there is the following:

$F$ is a sheaf, embeded in an injective sheaf $I$, giving an exact sequence:

$0 \to F \to I \to C \to 0$.

The author then restricts via $i_* i^{-1}$, notation: $i_* i^{-1} F = F_j$, to get a sequence

$0 \to F_j \to I_j \to \bar{C_j} \to 0$, where $\bar{C_j}$ is not the restriction of $C$, but rather the quotient sheaf of $I_j / F_j$.

The author seems to suggest that this quotient $\bar{C_j}$ is a proper subsheaf of $C_j$ (the restriction of $C$). I do not understand why it should be a proper subsheaf, since it feels to me that $i_* i^{-1}$ should be exact in this situation.

Is there a good example to think about?

Later on he proves in a stronger circumstance that $\bar{C_j} = C_j$.

(This is on the course to proving Serre's vanishing theorem about the cohomology of quasi-coherent sheaves on affine schemes.)

Comment: Yes, $i_* i^{-1}$ is exact if $i : U \to X$ is an open embedding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, the functor $i_*:Sh(U)\rightarrow Sh(X)$ is not exact. But before I'll give some examples, let me point out that this is not true that the stalk of $i_*i^{-1}\mathcal{F}$ at $x$ is either $\mathcal{F}_x$ or $0$ depending on whether $x\in U$ or not. There is the so called extension by zero functor $i_!$ which has this property.

Indeed, take $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $U=\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$. Then $(i_*\mathbb{Z})_0=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$. This is because for any small enough neighborhood $V$ of $0$, $V\cap U$ has two connected components.

The functor $i_*$ is not exact, and it has higher direct images. For example, on $X=\mathbb{C}$ and $U=\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, $R^1i_*i^{-1}\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Z}_0$ is a skyscraper sheaf placed at the origin. This is because for any small enough neighborhood $V$ of $0$, $V\cap U$ is homotopically a circle.

This gives an example where the functor $i_*i^{-1}$ is not exact : consider the exponential sequence on $X=\mathbb{C}$ :
$$0\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathcal{O}\overset{\exp}\rightarrow\mathcal{O}^\times\rightarrow 0$$
where $\mathcal{O}$ is the sheaf of holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathcal{O}^\times$ the sheaf of non vanishing holomorphic functions. If you apply $i_*i^{-1}$ you get :
$$0\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow i_*\mathcal{O}\rightarrow i_*\mathcal{O}^\times\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_0\rightarrow 0$$
This sequence means that a non vanishing holomorphic function $f$ defined on $V\setminus\{0\}$ where $V$ is a neighborhood of $0$ has a logarithm if and only if the residue of $f'/f$ at $0$ is zero.

Comment: Thank you for these enlightening examples! Can I ask why $R^1 i_* i^{-1} \mathcal{O} = 0$? (The last zero in the final diagram.)

Comment: I guess I want to know if this follows for some cohomological reason, or one has to invoke a theorem from complex analysis. Now I'm not sure that the statement as you put is completely correct - z is a nonvanishing holomorphic function on $V \setminus {0}$, with zero residue, but it doesn't have a logarithm. I guess you need to say something about the singularity at $0$ being non-removable, but this doesn't seem to be built into the exact sequence. I'm confused now.

Comment: Also it is really interesting to me that the boundary map is an integral. What is going on?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to take the residue of $f'/f$, I'll edit that. This also explains that this is an integer.

Comment: Also, when writing about this 4-terms exact sequence, I just meant that $i_*\mathcal{O}^\times\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_0$ was onto, so that I could end the long exact sequence here. But this is true that $R^1i_*\mathcal{F}=0$ for any coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$. This follows from the fact that there exist a fundamental system of neighborhood $V$ of $0$ such that $V$ and $V\setminus\{0\}$ are Stein spaces (similarly for the algebraic case with "Stein" replaced by "affine"), and that coherent sheaves have vanishing cohomology on Stein spaces (resp affine spaces).

Comment: Alternatively, we could have use the sheaf of continuous functions (instead of holomorphic) and still get the same exact sequences. The $R^1i_*\mathcal{C}=0$ because $\mathcal{C}$ is a fine sheaf (and is acyclic for any $f_*$). The residue has the following description then (which is maybe more enlightening) : a non vanishing map $f:V\setminus\{0\}\rightarrow\mathcal{C}^\times$ induces a map $f_*:\pi_1(V\setminus\{0\})\rightarrow\pi_1(\mathbb{C}^\times)=\mathbb{Z}$, the residue is then the value of $f_*$ at a small loop around $0$.